# Uniformly convergence on the convergent circle for complex power series!

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

The power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ has convergent radius $r>0$,
so $f(z)$ is analytic in $|z|<r$. MOREOVER, we suppose $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is continuous on the closed disk $|z|\leq r$.
My question is that: Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ converge uniformly on the closed disk $|z|\leq r$?
In my opinion, I can give a example such as: the series 
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$$
has radius $r=1$ and converges uniformly on the closed unit disk $|z|\leq1$.
I do not know whether my question is right or wrong. Any hints will welcome!

Comment: That's an example where the series converges uniformly. But it does not answer the question! To answer the question you either have to give an example where $f$ is continuous on $|z|=r$ but the series does not converge uniformly, or show that continuity _implies_ uniform convergence.

Comment: The example I gives  implies my question maybe right!

Comment: If you say so. "maybe right" or not, it's not true: In fact assuming $f$ is continuous on $|z|=r$ does _not_ imply uniform convergence. A counterexample is not quite trivial...

Comment: I do not know the count-example, can you give me the  reference or the website! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Goggling "uniformly convergent fourier series" led to a wikipedia article that says this: "There exist continuous functions whose Fourier series converges pointwise but not uniformly; see Antoni Zygmund, Trigonometric Series, vol. 1, Chapter 8, Theorem 1.13, p. 300."

Comment: In my situation, we deal with power series, and you mean "There exist continuous functions whose power series converges pointwise but not uniformly"?